# Error D8022: Cannot Open xxx.rsp in TFS2012

Tags: c++, build, tfs, tfsbuild

I've been stuck with this error for a couple days now with one of our C++ products.  This only occurs when I trigger the build in TFS.

Here are the details:

- It is a VS2005 solution with a few C++ projects in it
- We are using TFS2012 Update 3
- MSBuild Platform is x86
- Opening the solution in VS2005 and building does not generate this
  error
- Full error message, cl : Command line error D8022: cannot open
  'xxx.rsp'

I've tried:

- Changing the intermediate and output directories to point to
  different locations
- Changing project dependencies so projects are dependent on each other
- Disabled parallel builds
- Gave my build account admin rights

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! :)

**EDIT**

After looking around the logs some more, it seems like the build isn't generating the .rsp files before attempting to locate them.

I noticed when building locally my log displays some warnings before it creates the .rsp file, while the build server lacks these warnings.  They both should generate these warnings prior to the .rsp creation.

So my new question is, how do I resolve this race case?

Comment: RSP files are MSBuild response files - essentially MSBuild.exe command line switches. I don't think it's an issue with your project, rather it's how your project is hooked into the build.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I'm not doing anything fancy with the build, just added the solution to the project list.